# Q: How to calculate 'hub integration' / how many of your link-neighbors are also my link-neighbors?

Tags: netlogo

In the model I am building I need to make turtles calculate the 'hub integration' of their link-neighbors. By 'hub integration'(HI) I mean the following: **HI = number-of-shared-neighbors/n-of-your-neighbors**.

HI is a value that the 'turtle x' assigns to every other turtle that shares a link with her (we will call every linked turtles as 'turtle y'). The value of HI is thus the fraction of the number of nodes that are linked to both turtles x and y, with the number of nodes linked to turtle y.

I am using as references the Netlogo dictionary and the book 'An Introduction to Agent-Based Modeling' from Wilensky and Rand. Still, without the help of this community it would be really hard for me, if not impossible, to learn more advanced procedures.

EDIT 3 ---

I am greatly thankful for all the help received. I finally have a running procedure.

For the record, my final code of the 'hub integration procedure' is the following:

```
to find-hi
  ask turtles [
  foreach  sort link-neighbors [
  ask ? [
  if count [my-links] of self > 1 and count [my-links] of myself > 1 [
  let hi ( calc-HI self myself  )
  run-procedure  ] ] ] ]
end


to-report calc-HI [ XX YY ]
  let sizeX count [my-links] of XX
  let sizeY count [my-links] of YY
  let sizeXY count (turtle-set [link-neighbors] of XX [link-neighbors] of YY)
  report (sizeX + sizeY - sizeXY) / sizeY
end
```

Comment: There appears to be a conceptual difficulty here. If turtle X has 3 link neighbours (Y1, Y2 and Y3), the value of HI will presumably be different for each. So you need to be passing Y (and possibly X) to the HI calculation procedure. Otherwise, how does it know which one to calculate it for?

Comment: I think i see your point. Just to be sure, you please specify what do you mean by passing Y to the hi calculation procedure?

Comment: see my answer for a procedure where the two turtles are nominated when the procedure is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to count the number of neighbours, not list them all out.

One approach to count the number in common is to count the neighbours of X, count the neighbours of Y and count the agents who are either neighbours of X or Y. A turtle who is a neighbour of both X and Y will still only appear once in the agentset constructed, so the size of the intersection is the sum of the individual counts then subtract the size of the union.

This code expects you to nominate two turtles and reports the HI of turtle YY from the perspective of turtle XX (note that there is no checking that the two turtles have a link between them). I am not sure I have understood the calculation that you want, but you can amend as required.

```
to-report calc-HI [ XX YY ]
  let sizeX count [my-links] of XX
  let sizeY count [my-links] of YY
  let sizeXY count (turtle-set [link-neighbors] of XX [link-neighbors] of YY)
  report (sizeX + sizeY - sizeXY) / sizeY
end
```

Comment: Thank you. What you wrote is correct, but I am a bit confused by the report line. I just need to report the number of the shared turtles between x and y. I am missing why  sizeY / (sizeX + sizeY - sizeXY).
I added a reply to my initial comment to clarify the procedure.

Comment: Your formula in bold has number of shared / number of neighbour's links. This is the formula I used.

Comment: My apologies, I just realized it. The procedure you suggested calculates HI, and not just the nominator. That's perfect! I have one last question. When I run the procedure --- ask turtles [ if [calc-HI] of link-neighbors = 1 [run procedure]---- i get the error "calc-Hi expected 2 inputs". Why is it so? Isn't calc-Hi a single value?

Comment: There are two inputs to the procedure (named XX and YY), so you need to pass both turtles (eg `calc-HI turtle 0 turtle 1` would calculate HI of turtle 1 from the perspective of turtle 0

Answer (score 1):

You're using print in your reporter, try using `report` instead.

E.G.:

```
to-report who-of-neighbors
  report [who] of link-neighbors
end
```

More info on [to-report right here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#to-report).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You are correct. The report procedure is the way to go. I however still encounter an error in the procedure: 

 ////` to-report numerator
     ask link-neighbors [
    report count [filter member? who-of-neighbors my-who-of-neighbors]
  ]
end`
////
-- I would like the numerator to report the number of the shared neighbors. But i must be doing some mistake with the filter command.

Comment: Did you change all the `print` for `report`? Because that's what you want to do first.